# Agrupar determinado numero de TOP en consulta

Tags: sql, agrupación

Buen día.

Tengo la siguiente tabla "Importes", en Sql Server 2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El numero de registros es "n" es decir hice esa tabla para hacer la demostración, pero puede tener como 100 o 1000, pero lo importante es que quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder dar el TOP 10, agrupando por idEntidad.

Es decir que me diera los 10 Nombres que más han pagado para la Entidad 1, para la Entidad 2 ... y n entidades.

Actualmente hago una consulta para sumar los repetidos ya ordeno de mayor a menor.

```
SELECT nombre,SUM(Importe) as Pagado,idEntidad 
FROM Importes
GROUP BY Nombre,IdEntidad
ORDER BY IdEntidad,SUM(Importe)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde quisiera poder traér solo los TOP 4 ó n numero de TOP, intenté hacerlo con:

```
SELECT TOP 5 nombre,SUM(Importe) as Pagado,idEntidad 
FROM Importes
GROUP BY Nombre,IdEntidad
ORDER BY IdEntidad,SUM(Importe)
```

Pero solo me muestra los  5 primeros, después de hacer la agrupación. A lo que quisiera saber si se puede llegar es a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan apoyar. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Que gestor de base de datos usas, SQL SERVERM MYSQL ?

Comment: sql server, amigo.

Comment: Ya te conteste, pruébalo y me comentas si es lo que buscas, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo si te entendí bien esto te podría ayudar, te apoyarías de un CTE para calcular unos números y que este te de los 5 primeros ,
El campo row_num lo que hará es que te contara las veces que se repite es decir 1,2,3,4,5 etc, entonces ya con eso después de decimos a la consulta, solo tráeme donde row_num sea <=5 para que traiga los 5 primeros que encontró

```
;WITH CTE_Agru AS (
SELECT nombre,SUM(Importe) as Pagado,idEntidad ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY IdEntidad
      ORDER BY nombre
   ) row_num
FROM Importes
GROUP BY Nombre,IdEntidad)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Agru WHERE row_num<=5
Order by IdEntidad,Pagado
```

Aqui te anexo informacion sobre los CTE

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Un pequeño ejemplo funcional que se realizo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c23bbd480c740bbc322eded2d9393436